# Display nested object to array in table with ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an array:

```
fooData = [
    {value: 1, children: [{value: 2}, {value: 3}, {value: 4}, {value: 5}]},
    {value: 6, children: [{value: 7}, {value: 8}, {value: 9}, {value: 10, children: [{value: 11}]}]},
];
```

Without changing the array, how to display it using ngFor to get a inline table like this:

```
 <table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively pluck from your array, the property `value`. Once you have that, you'll have linear array which you can loop through and display.

Here is your recursive pluck function:

```
function pluckRecursive(input, prop, collect) {
    collect = collect || [];

    if (_.isArray(input)) {
        _.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
            pluckRecursive(value, prop, collect);
        })    
    } else if (_.isObject(input)) {
        _.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
            if (key === prop) {
                collect.push(value);
            } else {
                pluckRecursive(value, prop, collect);
            }
        })    
    }

    return collect;
};
```

Use this function to pluck your values:

```
arrayToDisplay: number[] = pluckRecursive(this.fooData, 'value');
```

Then display like so:

```
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of arrayToDisplay"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebfhhe) StackBlitz illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Define a ng-template element to display the value property and use ng-container to activate the same template recursively for children property. And I have added the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhwdza).

```
<table>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="common" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{link:fooData}">
    </ng-container>
</table>

<ng-template #common let-link='link'>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of link">
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngIf="data.children" [ngTemplateOutlet]="common" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{link:data.children}">
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: What about the last value 11 children of 10 ?

Comment: @TSR check the updated answer. I'll update the most simplified one.